# Find all the $c \ge 0$ for which $\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty }a _{n}$ is absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis

We consider: $$a_{1}=c-1$$ $$a_{n+1}= \frac{-n}{n+c \cdot \sqrt[n]{ln(n^{9876}+17)}}\cdot a_{n}, n\ge 1$$ $$c\ge0$$
I want to use Rabbe Test, because then in a simple way it comes out that the series is convergent for every $c>1$. However I have two doubts:
1) Raabe Test is for $a_{n}>0$, but if I do $r_{n}=n(|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}|-1)$ I knew that I must removing minus at $n$ and then I can leave the module. Hovewer I'm not sure if it's allowed. 2) If Raabe Test is a good way to do this task I knew only when my series is convergent, but I don't knew when is absolutely convergent so the more I do not know if Raabe Test is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $b_n := | a_n |$, and observe that $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n$ is absolutely convergent iff $\sum_{n \geq 1} b_n$ is convergent.

If $c \neq 1$, then the $b_n$'s are positive, so we may use Raabe's test to test the convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 1} b_n$. This will tell us about whether or not $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Carrying this out, we have
$$ n \left(  \frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} - 1\right) = c \sqrt[n]{\log n^{9876} + 17} \ \to \  c {\rm \ \ as \ \ } n \to \infty.$$

So $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n$ is absolutely convergent if $c > 1$ and not absolutely convergent if $c < 1$.

The $c = 1$ case is special. When $c = 1$, we have $ a_n = 0$ for all $n \geq 1$. So the series is trivially absolutely convergent - it sums to zero.

Comment: $b_n$'s are positive when $c\neq 1$. When $c=1$ we can't use Raabe's test

Comment: @Jakobian Sorry, I reorganised the answer.